# excel formula to calculate the progress based on the start and end date

Tags: google-sheets

i have following table in excel google sheets:

```
current date: 23/04/2023

name      | start date | end date   | progress | condition |
------------------------------------------------------------
project 1 | 17/01/2023 | 30/03/2023 |    100%  | completed |
project 2 | 24/01/2023 | 04/04/2023 |    100%  | failed    |
project 3 | 15/02/2023 | 15/05/2023 |     80%  | progress  |
```

based on the table, i need to automatically determine the progress for every project coming to the end date, the progress will coming to 100%. Currently for the condition i change the value from the table cell manually whether the project completed or still need more additional time(failed).

for project 3, currently i calculate them by month. So, 4(this is current month)/5 = 80%. Also i don't know how to do the same way if the project will start from the different year like from 20/12/2023 to 10/02/2024

Or maybe, you have any better idea? Thanks.

Comment: How do you differentiate between complete and failed?  They look exactly the same to me.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Currently for the condition i checking(change the value from the table cell) each of them manually whether the project completed or still need more additional time(failed). I will edit my question :)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to have the % of progress in time based on the exact date and than if it hits 100% it should be on completed? Or is the progress column connected to another sheet where you keep track of tasks that change the % of progress in this tab?

Comment: @SamiChouchane the progress column value is the result from the calculation of `start date` and `end date`.Currently for the condition, i write each of them manually.

Comment: Your goal is still unclear. From 2023-02-15 to 2023-05-15 is a three month period. Your progress example is in fifths at 80%. Your example also ignores the start date, ignores the current day of the month, and instead simply divides the current date's month by the end date's month. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: @JoelReid sorry if there's a mistake. basically i want to auto calculate the progress based on the month.